# Bug adding negative to positive floating point values

Tags: javascript

i am currently working on a matrice math lib in javascript which i have already finished my inverse function for 2x2, 3x3, and for 4x4 matrices using a adjugated cofactor mathod, when i went to multiply my inverse by my original matrice to get the identity matrix to validate my work i noticed a issue, while my diagonal of 1 was correct, where what should have been zeros where not in some places, i checked my work over several times with the help of external calculators and manually checking and i came to the conclusion it wasn't my multiplication.

i then decided to add the numbers for the number in question myself using javascript and the results are very confusing to say the least

`4.210526315789474 + 0.6263157894736841 + -0.1578947368421052 + -4.678947368421052`

when added in javascript output

`8.881784197001252e-16`

when added manually or using a calculator output

`0.0000000000000009`

so i did some more testing and decided to add

`-4.836842105263157 + 4.836842105263158`

to check if adding just the two sums would output the correct number and sure enough it did....

so my question is, why does

`4.210526315789474 + 0.6263157894736841 + -0.1578947368421052 + -4.678947368421052`

output the incorrect value, i am truly confused right now, thank you for the help in advanced,

my work environment is in chrome version +63 running js 1.7, all my output was to the developer console using console.log();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: See also https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate/21895757)

Comment: sorry if this might be a duplicate i searched on google for a while trying to find a question similar on stack and nothing came up, thank you for the links i will look into them (=

Comment: @daniel If I may make a suggestion, if you learn how to convert a fractional decimal number to binary by hand, it will help to understand this.  Some decimal values simply can't be represented accurately in binary.

Comment: @Amy thanks for the advice and links i appreciate it

Comment: @Amy i found that by just rounding in the precision of the floats to around that of a double aka 8 places of precision the math is now correct without error